# HttpClient's equivalent of HttpWebRequest's ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime property

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm converting old .NET code to the .NET 4.5 framework.

One particular method I'm updating is changing a [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to a [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) call. The existing code calls to an external Web API.

It's fairly straight forward, except that there's code in the existing HttpWebRequest code that assigns a value to the request's `ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime`. What's the equivalent of this for a HttpClient.

**Edit**
Here's how the `HttpWebRequest` is set.

```
var webReq = WebRequest.Create(API_ENDPOINT) as HttpWebRequest;

webReq.Method = "POST";
webReq.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
webReq.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1000 * 10;
```

Comment: The very same. `ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime` is a "global" setting that affects both classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just updated my question. It looks like it's set on the instance of the HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Chrome won't let me delete the previous comment. HttpClient uses HttpWebRequest underneath so you should be able to get the ServicePoint for a URL with [ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5f0atwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global static class `ServicePointManager` to set the `ServicePoint` idle limit.  You can also use the `FindServicePoint(uri)` method to get reference to the individual `ServicePoint` to modify after the initial call.  Alternatively you can use groups